# Fundamental period of $5 \sin(5 \pi t) + 5 \sin(3 \pi t)$

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing

f(t) = $5 \sin(5 \pi t) + 5 \sin(3 \pi t)$

$ w_1 = 5 \pi$

$w_2 = 3 \pi $

Formula to find combined period is:

$ T = \frac{2 \pi}{gcd} = \frac{2 \pi}{\pi} = 2 $

gcd = greatest common divisor of angular frequencies $5 \pi$ and $3 \pi $, which is $ \pi$

Wolfram [agrees](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=period%20of%20(5%20sin(5pi%20t)%20%2B%205%20sin(3pi%20t))) that period is T $= 2$

Is this formula legit?

Comment: `greatest common divisor of 5π and 3π, which is 15π`  No, why would it be $15 \pi\,$? `also saw that fundamental period of this function is 15` Where? `for some reason, wolfram says` How about you stop and think what the minimum positive $T$ could be such that $f(t)=f(t+T)\,$, instead.

Comment: @dxiv I confused with LCM, I need formula. Can't think rn.

Comment: `Can't think` Give it a honest try, at least ;-) Does $T=2$ work (why)? Could $T$ be less than $2$ (why)? You'll improve your chances at better answers by at least attempting *something*.

Comment: @dxiv this requires heavy thinking, I'd just rather get formula to get hw done asap, and do the thinking later. I don't see how T = 2 works, or how any other T would work. Both functions have different periods, 2/5 and 2/3. Those numbers aren't helpful, such as sin(t) which has a period of 2pi. 2pi I can visualize on the unit circle, 2/3 or 2/5 with such sines, I can't.

Comment: `this requires heavy thinking, I'd just rather get formula to get hw done asap` You appear to have google'd it already, why bother. (-1)

Comment: @Jack Math is all about thinking - thinking about what patterns can be observed, or about how to approach a question, or about why something is true. If you want a simple formula so that you can slack off and not understand anything, that's fine. However, I would strongly suggest you keep your mouth shut on this site.

Comment: @TobyMak >"I would strongly suggest you keep your mouth shut on this site" whatever helps you sleep at night, internet tough guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can say,
$$5(\sin (5πt)+\sin (3πt))$$$$$$
$$\frac{5}{2}(\sin (\frac{8πt}{2})\cos (\frac{2πt}{2}))$$$$$$
$$\frac{5}{2}(\sin (4πt)\cos (πt))$$$$$$
$$5(\sin(πt)\cos(2πt) \cos^2(πt))$$$$$$
Here $\sin(πt)$ has period $2$ $$$$ $\cos(2πt)$ has period $1$ $$$$ $\cos^2(πt)$ has period $1$ 
$$$$
Therefore total period is $2$